# UITableView reuse Questions

Tags: ios, uitableview

About UITableView reuse, when there are multiple different Cell, use a different identifier to distinguish good or use an identifier and the Cell subViews remove, add content again good, if the Cell is very many cases, these reusable, what kind of specific access rules, when an identifier in the queue on the position is how to remove the master answer, thank you

```
_testTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_testTableView.dataSource = self;
_testTableView.delegate = self;
[_testTableView setRowHeight:80.];
[self.view addSubview:_testTableView];

[_testTableView registerClass:[TestTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:testKeyOne];
[_testTableView registerClass:[TestTwoTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:testKeyTwo];
```

//one way
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
//one
if(indexPath.row < 15){

    TestTableViewCell * oneCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:testKeyOne forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return oneCell;

}else{

    TestTwoTableViewCell * oneCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:testKeyTwo forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return oneCell;

}

return nil;
```

}

two way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:testKeyOne forIndexPath:indexPath];

for(UIView * view in cell.subviews){

    [view removeFromSuperview];

}

//[cell addSubview:];

return cell;
```

}

one way or two,or Other better way，and Reuse of specific originally, enter the reuse and take out the order of the queue order

Comment: please explain correctly, what you exactly want to do....

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand what your question is, please make your question clearer, and please use punctuation mark (ex. question mark).

Answer (score 0):

You want to go with option one. The table view data source should not be adding or removing views from table view cells. That just gets too messy.

Another option is to have just one cell subclass, but code the subclass to hide and show views as needed. I wouldn't have it add and remove views. That's way more complex code and way more expensive time-wise, which isn't great when you're trying to get a high frame rate when scrolling.